# How to prove $a_{n+1}=(1+a_n+a^2_{n-1})/3$ is a non-decreasing sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, induction, monotone-functions

$$a_1=a_2=0.5$$

It isn't hard to show that $0.5\le a_n\lt 1$, and that if the sequence converge, the limit is 1.

But how to prove it's monotone?

I've tried:
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1-2a_n+a^2_{n-1}}{3}\ge 0$$
$$\frac{1+a^2_{n-1}}{2}\ge a_n$$
$$1-a_n \ge a_n - a^2_{n-1}$$

But couldn't prove any of the inequalities.

Comment: @Somos not yet, will try now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hint.

By induction:
$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}-a_n&=\frac{1-2a_n+a_{n-1}^2}{3}
\\&=\frac{\frac{3}{3}-2\frac{1+a_{n-1}+a^2_{n-2}}{3}+\frac{3a_{n-1}^2}{3}}{3}
\\&=\frac{1-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}^2+2(a_{n-1}^2-a_{n-2}^2)}{9}
\\&\geq0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: In my shame, I could not follow your arithmetic. But it gave me the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @User You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Following the implicit advice from [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3063434/61487) to use the definition twice together with induction,

$$a_{n+1}=(1+a_n+a^2_{n-1})/3$$
$$a_{n}=(1+a_{n-1}+a^2_{n-2})/3$$
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=(a_n-a_{n-1}+a^2_{n-1}-a^2_{n-2})/3$$

If we assume $a_n \ge a_{n-1} \ge a_{n-2}$ we get $a_{n+1} \ge a_n$